# Is Paul quoting the “Apocrypha” in Colossians 1:17?

Tags: pauline-epistles

Sirach 43:26 (KJV) “By him the end of them hath prosperous success, ***and by his word all things consist***.”

Colossians 1:17 (KJV) “And he is before all things, ***and by him all things consist***.”

Is Sirach 43 the background for Paul's argument that by Jesus, as the word of God, all things consist?